# Stubbing a library dependency

Tags: c++, testing, cmake

I have following problem referring to a 3rd party library stubbing in test environment.

```
MyLibTest - gtest test executable
MyLib - my library
DriverLib - the lib I want to stub in the test
DriverLibStub - stub
```

The structure looks like this:

```
MyLibTest -> links to MyLib
MyLib -> links to DriverLib
```

My intuition is that it should be like this, but I don't know the details - I mean, how to do it properly.

```
MyLibTest -> links to MyLib, DriverLibStub
```

Now how can I directly replace DriverLib with DriverLibStub in MyLibTest target?

Comment: No direct way, What I usually do : first define an abstract baseclass modeling the methods of the library you use. Then inject that interface into the code that needs to "talk" to the library. And then make 2 implementations one forwarding to the library and one mock. This also allows you to add things before calls make it into the 3rd party library code. e.g. calling the third party code using an executor (use one thread to communicate with the likely not threadsafe 3rd party code, do logging, add pre/post condition checks, and sometimes do the ugly things like a const cast.

Comment: MyLibTest will then instantiate the mock and link with DriverLibStub. While your executable will instantiate the code interacting with the 3rd party code and link with DriverLib.

Comment: are MyLib and MyLibTest static or shared libraries? If they're shared, you can probably use loading tricks. see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/22926/550426 (`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and/or `RPATH`)